# How can I use setAttribute to set multiple classes on an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

How can I set an element to have multiple classes?

Initial attempt:

```
element.setAttribute("class","class1","class2");
element.className="class1 , class2";
element.class="class1 , class2";
```

Comment: Does the element initially have any classes set?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just set the attribute as normal. It just sets the attribute to whatever string you pass it, it isn't aware of any special rules for how the value gets handled.

The attribute takes a space separated list of classes so:

```
element.setAttribute("class","class1 class2");
```

However… older versions (I think 7 and lower) of Internet Explorer have serious bugs in their `setAttribute` implementation — so don't use it. Use the `className` property instead.

```
element.className = "class1 class2";
```

Note, also, that these are *HTML classes*. They uses beyond the application of styles. There is no such thing as a CSS class (although there are class selectors, other selectors, rule sets and properties, all of which have been (incorrectly and confusingly) called "classes" at some time or another).

Comment: so the ',' must have been tripping me up. Thanks

Comment: element.className = "class1 class2"; => in IE8 sets only first class name

Answer (score 7):

The attribute `className` is a space-separated list of values.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "class1 class2";
```

(notice the space instead of comma between the two names)

Or, if you want to add on to the classes already there:

```
    document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " class1 class2";
```

Answer (score 3):

if you're looking to append (not destory current classes), I would do

```
element.className = element.className + " anotherclass yetanotherclass"
```

Comment: The leading space here is important. Otherwise you wind up with `firstclassanotherclass yetanotherclass `.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use commas. Just set the class name with spaces between multiple classes. I would use jQuery addClass method- if you are are using jQuery :).

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to use `element.className += "classname"` so that the new class gets appended to the list of classes already present.

Comment: it would be element.className += " classname" (note the space for seperation from the others)

Answer (score 1):

```
`element.className = "class1" + " class2" + " class3"`;
```

or even

```
element.className = ["class1","class2","class3"].join(" ")
```

This with rewrite all previous classes. 
 In modern browsers every DOM element also have a `classList` collection you can access. It has `add`, `remove` and `toggle` methods. It is a good example of how javascript frameworks influenced standard APIs itself.

Comment: This will not work because the class names will not be separated by spaces, which is necessary.

Comment: Oh @Jason, it is totally OK. We live in a cruel world, where on should be very careful while producing code snippets )

Answer (score 1):

Easy if you can hook it to an `ID`

```
document.getElementById("a").className = "newClass anotherClass";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qaBQv/1/

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be the correct answer:

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementById("divName");
yourDiv.SetAttribute("class","RedClass"); 
yourDiv.SetAttribute("className","RedClass");
```

Never seen it done using `className` like that (e.g., yourDiv.className...).

Answer (score 0):

Even **without** using **setAttribute** you could add multiple classes for an element by **classList** property (which is supported by all modern browsers).

```
// add or remove multiple classes
element.classList.add("foo", "bar", "baz");
element.classList.remove("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

Few more useful stuffs you can do using **classList**

Find and Replace:

```
// replace class "foo" with class "bar"
element.classList.replace("foo", "bar");
```

Check for class existence:

```
// check a class is exist for the element
console.log(element.classList.contains("foo")); // return true/false
```

Toggle class in/out:

```
// add the class 'foo' if the element doesn't have class 'foo'
// remove the class 'foo' if the element has the class 'foo'
console.log(element.classList.toggle("foo")); // true - class was added otherwise false.
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is

```
Element.className = "class1 class2";
```