# setAttribute not working with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get this code working:

HTML:

```
<li><a class="main-but" href="#" id="click-no-po" onclick="porch_off('main-cpo');activeSelectPorOff();" >No Porch</a></li>
```

Script:

```
function activeSelectPorOff() {
    document.getElementById('click-no-po').setAttribute('class', 'main-but active');
    document.getElementById('click-cpo').setAttribute('class', 'main-but');
}
```

The `potch_off` function is running fine but I can't seem to get it setting the attribute.

I am not the most proficient with jQuery and JavaScript but I am trying.

Comment: Console errors? That's the first place you should look.

Comment: Is jQuery involved anywhere here? I’m not seeing it. Does `porch_off` work properly?

Comment: Kinda dupe-ish? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860213/multiple-css-classes-using-setattribute-javascript

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute` for classes. Instead, set the `.className` property, like `document.getElementById('click-no-po').className = 'main-but active'`

Comment: try -- document.getElementById('click-no-po').classList.add("the-class");  ----- http://callmenick.com/post/add-remove-classes-with-javascript-property-classlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to add Class:

```
$("#click-no-po").addClass('main-but active');
```

Or this to remove Class:

```
$("#click-no-po").removeClass('main-but active');
```

Don't forget to use the ready function to ensure the js code finds the ID.

Comment: Thanks.  That works but after a few seconds the class "active' disappears on the code view in Chrome. Any reason?

Answer (score 1):

try toggle Class

```js
$('a.main-but').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{background:red;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="main-but" href="#">No Porch</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this if you are trying to use jquery [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
function activeSelectPorOff() {
    $('click-po').toggleClass('main-but');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, i on your test code, theres only  on element 'a' with id, so in your funcition

```
    function activeSelectPorOff() {
        document.getElementById('click-no-po').setAttribute('class', 'main-but active');
        document.getElementById('click-cpo').setAttribute('class', 'main-but');
    }
```

document.getElementById('click-cpo') return a null element, and when you try to read/write with .setAttribute() this trhows and exeption u can read atribute of null

```
    function activeSelectPorOff() {
        var a=document.getElementById('click-no-po');
        var b=document.getElementById('click-cpo').setAttribute('class', 'main-but');
        try{
          a.setAttribute('class', 'main-but active');
        }catch(e){
          console.log(e)
        }
        try{
          b.try{a.setAttribute('class', 'main-but active');
        }catch(e){
          console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

this should avoid the function to halt, another way, is to chech a!=null before trying to set up an attribute

Comment: Avoid `try...catch`. Use `if(a) a.setAttribute(...)`.